# PhpStorm remote debug: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

When I am trying to validate remote debug on PhpStorm I always get this error:

> Failed to execute validation script: 'sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target'

I googled and found some similar problems but non of them was relevant to me.

Also I get `Please, configure path to validation script and select deployment server` but that is configured correctly I checked that.

I am using xdebug on remote Apache server, PHP 7.2 and PhpStorm 2016.2.2.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You're using HTTPS, right? Can you fall back to HTTP?

Comment: I'm getting same error. I changed https to http in Deployment settings. Anywhere else protocol was not specified.

Comment: Could you please submit a ticket to our helpdesk? SO is not really convenient for issue investigation https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us